# Android AlarmManager and BroadcastReceiver empty intent data

Tags: android, kotlin, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

I have found out that somethings work wrong on Android O. I have done the implementation of `Reminder` functionality. I wanted to send broadcast on fixed time. AlarmManager works correctly, BroadcastReceiver executes `onReceive` but the intent has no data. I have checked everything and while I set up alarm data is attached to the intent. I think that in past it was working well and something has happened in the meantime. Here is the code that shows how I set up `Intent`, `PendingIntent` and alarm.

```
Intent(context, AlarmReceiver::class.java).apply {
                action = System.currentTimeMillis().toString()
                putExtra(AlarmService.ID_KEY, alarmId)
                putExtra(AlarmService.CONTENT_TASK, task)
                putExtra(AlarmService.CONTENT_ID, task.localId.value)
                putExtra(AlarmService.CONTENT_STATUS, task.status)
                putExtra(AlarmService.CONTENT_TITLE_KEY, notificationTitle)
                putExtra(AlarmService.MESSAGE_KEY, notificationMessage)
            }
```

Pending intnet:

```
private fun createPendingIntent(context: Context, intent: Intent, alarmId: Int): PendingIntent {
    return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, alarmId, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)
}
```

Alarm:

```
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, AppGlobal.getTimeToMilisecond(task.date) - timeAgo, createPendingIntent(context, intent, alarmId))
```

I have also tried to fire Service by changing `BroadcastReceiver` to `IntentService` and `PendingIntent.getBroadcast` to `PendingIntent.getService` -> the result was the same. `onHandleIntent` was receiving `Intent` with no data. And by `no data` I mean that for example `intent.getStringExtra(AlarmService.CONTENT_STATUS)` returns null. How can I fix this problem?

EDIT:

I was thinking about changing approach. Maybe I should switch to `JobScheduler` to get rid of this error? What are your thoughts on my idea?

EDIT 2:

It turned out that there was a problem with serialization of my `Parcelable` object. I had `Parcelable` subobjects which had some problems with serialization. Unfortunately, this was not notified by Android O. I found out what is the problem after switching from device with `O` to older one.

Answer (score 0):

solved declaring the broadcast receiver of this way in the manifest

```
        <receiver android:name=".services.AlarmReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="false"
        >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.blogspot.shudiptotrafder.lifeschedular"/>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

and calling since my activity of this way

```
val intent = Intent(context, AlarmReceiver::class.java)
        intent.putExtra(ALARM_EXTRA, alarm)
        intent.putExtra("1123","Hola mundo!")
        val pIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                context,
                112358,
                intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
        )
        Log.e("1123 time seetteedd",nextAlarm.timeInMillis.toString())
        val am = context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager
        am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, nextAlarm.timeInMillis, pIntent)
```